# Filesystem changes using watchdog python and sent the file to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, python-watchdog

```
import pandas 
import os 
import sqlalchemy 
import sys 
import time from watchdog.observers 
import Observer from watchdog.events 
import FileSystemEventHandler

class EventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler): 
def on_any_event(self, event): 
print("EVENT") 
print(event.event_type) 
print(event.src_path) 
print() 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
path = 'input path here'

event_handler= EventHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
print("Monitoring started")
observer.start()
try:
    while(True):
       time.sleep(1)
       

except KeyboardInterrupt:
            observer.stop()
            observer.join()

engine = create_engine('Database information') 
cursor = engine.raw_connection().cursor()

for file in os.listdir('.'): 
file_basename, extension = file.split('.') 
if extension == 'xlsx': 
df = pd.read_excel(os.path.abspath(file)) 
df.to_sql(file_basename, con = engine, if_exists = 'replace')
```

so the first part where observer.join() ends i am okay with. but the next part where it starts with engine = create_engine("") that where i am having trouble with that part is suppose to send the file to the sql server but the code is not doing that i have researched the internet but having found anything. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Generally folks test their code and post the problems they are having.

Comment: Hi Chris:  I have tested the code and part of it works but the other part where it needs to send it to SQL i am having trouble in.

Comment: Based on your post we do not know what trouble you are having, just that you are having trouble. You need to add more details about the actual problem. Where does the code fail? What error messages are you receiving? What troubleshooting have you done to resolve the issue?